# Deadlock in gstreamer for Windows

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, gstreamer, deadlock

I use [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.8.1/) 1.8.1 library in my C# WinForms application which allows me to watch several RTSP video streams from video-server device simultaneously.

I wrote a native c++ dll which wraps calls to gstreamer. I use it from C# application via DllImport attribute.

Most of time everything works perfect. But sometimes (I think when connection with video-server is not stable) I have deadlock in `gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);` in my native dll.

All calls to gstreamer API make from main (GUI) thread. Deadlock occures very rare - only once per day. It's very tedious to catch this error and I don't know how to fix or work around it.

Here is some screenshots from Visual Studio debugger when deadlock is in action:

[image: debugger watch]
[image: call stack]

Source code of gstreamer wrapper dll is very small:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "gstreamer-1.0.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glib-2.0.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gobject-2.0.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gstvideo-1.0.lib")

GSTLIB_API void init()
{
    gst_init(NULL, NULL);
}

GSTLIB_API GstElement* create(const char* uri, const void* hwnd)
{
    GstElement* pipeline = gst_element_factory_make("playbin", "play");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(pipeline), "uri", uri, NULL);
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(pipeline), (guintptr)hwnd);
    return pipeline;
}

GSTLIB_API void play(GstElement* pipeline)
{
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
}

GSTLIB_API void stop(GstElement* pipeline)
{
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(pipeline), 0);
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(pipeline));
}

GSTLIB_API bool hasError(GstElement* pipeline)
{
    auto state = GST_STATE(pipeline);
    return state != GST_STATE_PLAYING;
}
```

C# binding for native dll:

```
[DllImport("GstLib.dll", EntryPoint = @"?init@@YAXXZ",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void init();

[DllImport("GstLib.dll", EntryPoint = @"?create@@YAPAU_GstElement@@PBDPBX@Z",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr create([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string uri, IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("GstLib.dll", EntryPoint = @"?stop@@YAXPAU_GstElement@@@Z",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void stop(IntPtr pipeline);

[DllImport("GstLib.dll", EntryPoint = @"?play@@YAXPAU_GstElement@@@Z",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void play(IntPtr pipeline);

[DllImport("GstLib.dll", EntryPoint = @"?hasError@@YA_NPAU_GstElement@@@Z",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
private static extern bool hasError(IntPtr pipeline);
```

Does anybody know why deadlock is occured?

Comment: Nothing better than wild speculation to offer, but if your theory regarding an unstable connection to the video server is the issue, you might be facing with a pending request of some sort back to the server while a stream is playing, and before that request is served, the stop fires, thus setting up at least the potential of a single stream both awaiting a request and pending a stop. Total shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

This may be just pure speculation on my end:

If you are setting the state of the pipeline in the streaming thread you actually have to do it calling [gst_element_call_async](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstelement.html?gi-language=c#gst_element_call_async). The GStreamer documentation states that calling [gst_element_set_state](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstelement.html?gi-language=c#gst_element_set_state) in the streaming thread might cause a deadlock:

> gst_element_call_async
>
> Calls func from another thread and passes user_data to it. This is to be used for cases when a state change has to be performed from a streaming thread, directly via gst_element_set_state or indirectly e.g. via SEEK events.
>
> Calling those functions directly from the streaming thread will cause deadlocks in many situations, as they might involve waiting for the streaming thread to shut down from this very streaming thread.
>
> MT safe.